# Basis functions on two Hilbert spaces - showing the dot product is the basis of the product Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Question: Let $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal N, \nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If functions $e_1, e_2 \ldots $ are a Hilbert space basis of $L^2(X)$ and functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots $ are a Hilbert space basis of $L^2(Y)$, prove that $e_i\cdot f_j$ is a basis of $L^2(X\times Y)$.

(Here $e_i\cdot f_j$ is a function on $X\times Y$ such that its value at $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ is $e_i(x)\cdot f_j(y)$.)

My Attempt: Assume that the basis functions are all orthonormal because if they are not, I could just use Graham Schmidt. I know that for any $x \in X$, $$x= \sum_n \langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$$ and for any $y \in Y$, $$y= \sum_m \langle y, f_m\rangle f_m$$
Now, for any element $z \in X \times Y$, I want to show that we can write it using the $e_n$ and $f_n$ basis functions. This is where I am having a tough time and was hoping to get some help.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use the spanning criterion: Given $g \in L^2(X \times Y)$ such that $\langle g, e_i \cdot f_j \rangle = 0$ for all $i,j$, show that $g=0$. Also if your Hilbert spaces are over the complex numbers, if I'm not mistaken, you should have a complex conjugate on $f_j$, i.e. your basis should be $e_i(x) \overline{f_j}(y)$.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct about the Hilbert space conjugation in general. You wouldn’t be able to tell from my question, but I am just looking at real spaces right now. I appreciate your help. I am going to try and work that out using the spanning criterion.

Comment: @MisterRiemann I am wondering how showing the spanning criterion and g=0 if the inner product is 0 for all i,j shows that the new basis works for $L^2(X x Y)$... Sorry I am just not quite seeing it. :/

Comment: That criterion is a standard tool, and you should be able to find a proof of it in your favourite functional analysis book in the chapter on Hilbert spaces. I suppose I could type it as an answer if you are unable to find it.

Comment: @MisterRiemann If you don't mind helping me out I would really appreciate it. I tried looking in Kreyszig Functional Analysis and Folland Real Analysis and I didn't have much luck. I found a completeness criterion that states a result that given a orthonormal basis u_n, if <x,u_n>=0 for all n then x=0.  But I am not sure how to prove something is a basis like I want to. This is a problem on a study guide I am trying to use to prepare for the test... Thank you.

Comment: For the special case $L^2$ you may want to try using Fubini's theorem

Comment: @rubikscube09 would I use Fubini's theorem to show that for $g\in L^2(X \times Y)$ that $\langle g,e_i  f_j \rangle= \int_{X\times Y} ge_i f_j = \int_{X}(\int_Y  ge_i f_j)$  or something like that... I think I am missing something there...

Comment: Yes, for example, see Stein and Shakarchi's Analysis Vol 3., Chapter 5(Hilbert Spaces) Question 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify things slightly, I will only present the result for separable Hilbert spaces (i.e. the ones with a countable basis, which suffices in your case).

> Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal H$ an orthonormal system. Then
>   $$\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \text{ is a basis for }\mathcal H \quad\iff\quad \langle x,e_n\rangle=0 \;\text{ for all } n\geq1 \text{ implies that } x = 0. $$

Since you said that you found a proof for $(\Rightarrow)$ in the literature, I will only prove $(\Leftarrow)$. So suppose that $\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n\geq 1$ implies that $x=0$. Let $x \in \mathcal H$ and consider
$$ x_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j. $$
For $n > m$, we then have
\begin{align}
\Vert x_n-x_m \Vert^2 &= \left\Vert \sum_{j=m+1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j \right\Vert^2 = \left\langle \sum_{j=m+1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j, \sum_{j=m+1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j \right\rangle\\
&= \sum_{j=m+1}^n\sum_{k=m+1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle \overline{\langle x, e_k\rangle} \langle e_j, e_k \rangle = \sum_{j=m+1}^n |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^2,
\end{align}
since $\langle e_j, e_k \rangle = 0$ whenever $j\not=k$. This in fact shows that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, since
$$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^2\right)_{n=1}^\infty $$
is an increasing sequence which is upper bounded by $\Vert x\Vert^2$ (Bessel's inequality), and hence convergent, and in particular Cauchy.
Since $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space, it is complete, so $x_n$ converges:
$$ x_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j \to \tilde x = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j \in \mathcal H $$
It is easily checked that this limit is indeed equal to $x$, by proving that
$$ \langle x-\tilde x, e_n \rangle = \lim_{k\to\infty} \langle x-x_k, e_n \rangle = 0 $$
for all $n\geq 1$, and then using the assumption. Can you do that?

Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a life saver. I will make sure I understand this for the test.

Comment: @MathIsHard Glad I could help. Good luck!